# How to work with multiple sub-projects using IntelliJ, maven and spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spring-data-rest

I have two projects based on Spring Framework that share some common code. The common code consists of the models and rest repositories.

I want to do split the projects so that I can manage the common code from a single location. I also want to be able to work on the common code (in IntelliJ ) when I develop features for one of the two projects, without the need to compile, upload to a maven repository or something like that.

From my understanding so far I need to use maven modules but I don't quite understand how they all fit together. I am also concerned about the entity scan annotations in spring

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.project1.repositories")`
`@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.company.project1.models")`

I am worried that if I create a maven module, or a sub-project that will act as a library for the other two projects, Spring won't know how to pick up those repositories and models.

How can I split the two projects in three projects such that:

1. Any changes to the common project reflect automatically in both main projects
2. If I work on a main project and I need to change the common project, I can do that from IntelliJ without the need to open another project, edit, compile, push to a maven repository, etc
3. Spring picks up the rest repositories

Comment: You mentioned maven in the question, but your last sentence about not compiling and uploading to a repo implies you don't actually want to use maven.  If you split out the common code, which is a good idea,  then there has to be some mechanism for the other projects to resolve the dependency on the common code.  What's wrong with using maven?

Comment: let me know if the question makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to use this sort of maven structure:

features
       common
       feature-1
       feature-2

where features is the top level maven project and the others are sub-modules, and feature-1 and feature-2 have a dependency on the jar produced by common.

I'm not familiar with IntelliJ so I'm assuming that IDE supports this type of structure.  In Eclipse, when code changes in common, feature-1 and feature-2 can *usually* see it without having to do a maven build.  Sometimes Eclipse doesn't recognize a change and a maven build is required to update the cache.

Comment: Ok, so common's pom needs to have as parent features, so do feature-1 and feature-2. Also, I will put in feature-1's pom a dependency towards common ?